# Background process of subshell strange behaviour

Tags: bash, background-process, subshell

I wonder why some similar bash commands behave the way they do.

I have a bash script `foo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true
do
    echo "reading"
    read data
    echo $data
    echo "stderr msg" >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

It's an infinite loop which reads one line at a time from stdin and outputs that same line. I also have a bash script `bar`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./foo &
```

The following commands were run in `bash` (v. 4.4.19) in a terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 (let's assume the scripts reside in the working directory):

1. `./foo &`

   - Stops when it tries to read from stdin, in accordance with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217695/245169).
   - Killed when controlling terminal is killed, as expected.
2. `(./foo &)`

   - Appears to be automagically continuously fed with new input from stdin. Shouldn't it too stop when attempting to read from stdin? Whatever it's getting it doesn't show when echoed, thus I'm guessing it's EOF characters.
   - Continues running even after the controlling terminal is killed. Looking at the output of `ps`, the controlling terminal changes from pts/*x* to ?. How did this happen without the use of either `disown` or `nohup`? (However, after killing the originally controlling terminal, it yields a "write error: Input/output error" on every write, which I suppose is because its stdout was tied to the now closed terminal. Correct?)
3. `bash -c "./foo &"`

   Appears to behave exactly like 2).
4. `./bar`

   Appears to behave exactly like 2) and 3).
5. Adding `bash -c "~/foo"` (no `&`) as a startup application

   Behaves similarly to 2), 3) and 4), with the differences:

   - Its controlling terminal is the desktop tty*x*.
   - You can't (can you?) kill its controlling terminal.

   None of those differences seem odd to me, just the fact that it's continuously fed with new input.

My guess is that 2) - 5) all use a subshell of sorts whose stdin is redirected to something like `/dev/null`, though I'm very unsure and seek a more exact answer.

Comment: Try adding `echo $?` after `read data` to see if the read was successful.

Comment: EOF is not a character, it's a condition ("nothing more to read") of the input stream.

Comment: @Barmar Didn't think of that, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commands run with `&` in a shell *without* the job control enabled (eg. in a script or a `(...)` subshell) have their stdin redirected from `/dev/null` and `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` set to `SIG_IGN`. From the susv4 [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02):

> If job control is disabled (see `set`, `-m`), the standard input for an
>      asynchronous list, before any explicit redirections are performed,
>      shall be considered to be assigned to a file that has the same
>      properties as `/dev/null`. This shall not happen if job control is
>      enabled. In all cases, explicit redirection of standard input shall
>      override this activity.

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478697/308316) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481033/308316).

It's not true that your `./foo` script is "continuously fed" data -- it's getting an EOF when trying to read from `/dev/null` -- you should check the exit status of `read`.

Comment: It doesn't stop on EOF because there's no test on whether the `read` succeeded.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's was kind of an awkward retorical question, it should've been "why aren't you checking the exit status of read in your script".

Comment: Ah. Yes. I did kinda misunderstand.

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you! Regarding not checking for EOF: For some reason I thought the read would attempt to read past EOF and then crash the script, instead of endlessly reporting EOF, not sure where I got that idea from...

Comment: However, there's something I'm missing. The susv4 standard says that the ignored action for those signals is inherited from the executing shell. Doesn't that imply that the executing shell also ignores those signals? Because that doesn't appear to be the case. Are they ignored and then uningnored?

(Edit: At first this comment also asked about SIGHUP, but I believe you answered that in [the second referenced answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480934/process-killed-before-being-launched-in-background/481033#481033).)

Comment: @gblomqvist It's inherited through execve() not through fork(); the shell forks, sets those signals to ignore *in the child process* and then executes the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub shells are non-interactive; only interactive shells are automatically killed.