# sleep, wait and Ctrl+C propagation

Tags: bash, sleep, wait

If I have the following shell script

```
sleep 30s
```

And I hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> when the shell script is running, the `sleep` dies with it.

If I have the following shell script

```
sleep 30s &
wait
```

And I hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> when the shell script is running, the `sleep` continues on, and now has a parent of 1.

Why is that? Doesn't bash propagate <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to all the children?

EDIT:
If I have the following script

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :18.0 -ac -screen 0 1180x980x24 &
wait
```

where I am spawning a program, this time <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> on the main process kills the `Xvfb` process too.

So how/why is `Xvfb` different from sleep?

In the case of some processes I see that they get reaped by `init`, in some cases they die. Why does sleep get reaped by init? Why does `Xvfb` die?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr;** the `Xvfb` process sets a signal handler for `SIGINT` and exits when it receives such a signal, but the `sleep` process doesn't, so it inherits the "ignore" state for `SIGINT` as it was set by the shell running the script before executing the `sleep` binary.

When a shell script is run, the job control is turned off, and background processes (the ones started with `&`) are simply run in the same process group, with `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` set to `SIG_IGN` (ignored) and with their stdin redirected from `/dev/null`.

This is required by the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11):

> If job control is disabled (see the description of set -m) when the shell executes an asynchronous list, the commands in the list shall inherit from the shell a signal action of ignored (SIG_IGN) for the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals.

If the signal disposition is set to `SIG_IGN` (ignore), that state will be inherited through `fork()` and [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execle.html):

> Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process
>   image shall be set to the default action in the new process image.
>   Except for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling
>   process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image.

Comment: POSIX also forbid shells to allow undoing a SIG_IGN. `zsh` ignores that (unhelpful) requirement, so in `zsh`, you can work around it with `(trap - INT; sleep 30) &`. In other shells, you'd need to use `zsh -c 'trap - INT; exec sleep 30' &` or use `perl` or other things that don't have that silly requirement.

Comment: In recent versions of `bash`, the problem can be worked around by starting the command as a `coproc` instead of with `&`: `{ coproc sleep 30 < /dev/null >&4 4>&-; } 4>&1` which doesn't seem to ignore SIGINT/SIGQUIT...

Answer (score 5):

From the [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics):

> Background processes are those whose process group ID differs from the terminal’s; such processes are immune to keyboard-generated signals

You could handle this in different ways; first, to kill the listed jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' INT
sleep 30s &
wait
```

Alternatively, send a kill to all of the processes in the same process group:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill 0' INT
sleep 30s &
wait
```

Comment: That doesn't always seem to be the case though. For instance, if I have this in my shell script `usr/bin/Xvfb :18.0 -ac -screen 0 1180x980x24 &; wait` and I hit Ctrl+C on the parent process, it does call Xvfb too. Why is that? By this logic that process should continue to live, no?

Comment: @HariSundararajan.  Are you executing your script remotely through `putty` or similar?

Comment: no, I am sitting in front of the linux box, with the kvm attached to it, and running commands on an xterm.

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not forward signals like SIGINT or SIGTERM to processes it is currently waiting on.

One common workaround is to do a trap wait wait as shown in the following example:

```
int_handler()
{
    kill -TERM "${child_pid}" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

trap 'int_handler' INT

echo "Sleeping ... "
sleep 200 &

child_pid=$!
wait ${child_pid} > /dev/null 2>&1
trap - INT
wait ${child_pid} > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Why does it _appear_ to forward signals when I run certain other commands , such as Xvfb?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the second wait. Why is it needed ?