# Process started by script does not receive SIGINT

Tags: process, kill, signals, sigint

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (AWS)

I am creating a python process via this command:
`nohup python -u main.py > nohup.out 2>&1 &`

I would like to send a ctrl-c/SIGINT to the process, so I send `kill -2 <pid>`.

When I start the process from my terminal, this works fine, the program receives the keyboard interrupt and closes gracefully.

When I start the process via a `.sh` script or via another bash process (e.g. `bash -c 'nohup python -u main.py > nohup.out 2>&1 &'`). (I believe both methods start the process in the same way), the process does not receive the SIGINT when I send it.

SIGTERM (default `kill`) works normally and closes the process, but does not let the process close gracefully, but I need.

What's happening?

Answer (score 3):

No, they're not started in the same way. Since bash is running scripts with the job control turned off, the background mode of the commands started with `&` *from a script* is just "faked" by letting them ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT and redirecting their input from `/dev/null`.

See my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478697/308316) here (with references to the standard describing this).

In your case this also means the `main.py` isn't setting any handler for `SIGINT` in order to do a "graceful" exit, but it's just forcefully killed by a Control-C or `kill -2` when run from an interactive shell. If it did set a handler, that handler would've also overridden the `SIG_IGN` disposition of `SIGINT` set by the parent shell when run from a script.