# Behavior of directly vs indirectly backgrounded children on read

Tags: shell, terminal, signals, job-control

When I do

```
( sleep 1; read x ; echo x=$x; echo done ) &
```

then with the default terminal settings, the job gets stopped by `SIGTTIN`.

If I do

```
( ( sleep 1; read x ; echo x=$x; echo done ) & )
```

the `read` syscall inside `read` gets EOF (returns with 0)` and no stopping by SITTIN happens.

What is the explanation for these behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the second case the backgrounded command will be run in a subshell, and as there's no job control in subshells, the background mode will be faked by redirecting the input from `/dev/null` and ignoring the `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` signals.

See also these answers:

[Background process of subshell strange behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461386/background-process-of-subshell-strange-behaviour/490076#490076)

[Process started by script does not receive SIGINT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485630/process-started-by-script-does-not-receive-sigint/485637#485637)

[Does ` (sleep 123 &)` remove the process group from bash's job control?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491157/does-sleep-123-remove-the-process-group-from-bashs-job-control/491172#491172)

[Process killed before being launched in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480934/process-killed-before-being-launched-in-background/481033#481033)