# Process killed before being launched in background

Tags: shell, background-process, terminal-emulator, job-control, xfce4-terminal

I'm using a bash script `script.sh` containing a command `cmd`, launched in background:

```
#!/bin/bash
…
cmd &
…
```

If I open a terminal emulator and run `script.sh`, `cmd` is properly executed in background, as expected. That is, while `script.sh` has ended, `cmd` continues to run in background, with PPID 1.

But, if I open another terminal emulator (let say xfce4-terminal) from the previous one (or at the beginning of desktop session, which is my real use case), and execute `script.sh` by

```
xfce4-terminal -H -x script.sh
```

`cmd` is not properly executed anymore: It is killed by the termination of `script.sh`. Using `nohup` to prevent this is not sufficient. I am obliged to put a `sleep` command after it, otherwise `cmd` is killed by the termination of `script.sh`, before being dissociated from it.

The only way I found to make `cmd` properly execute in background is to put `set -m` in `script.sh`. Why is it necessary in this case, and not in the first one? Why this difference in behaviour between the two ways of executing `script.sh` (and hence `cmd`)?

I assume that, in the first case, monitor mode is *not* activated, as one can see by putting `set -o` in `script.sh`.

Comment: Note: file extensions of executables is bad practice. (what happens to calling scripts if you re-write in a different language?)

Comment: `xterm -e nohup ./script` works for me.  Maybe an xfce issue?

Comment: @stefan No, you're cheating ;) This works also for me with `xfce4-terminal` or `gnome-terminal`. The point is that `nohup` has to be putted *in* the script, we don't want all the script being affected by `nohup`, but just `cmd`.
That said, it is interesting that it works in this case, without changing anything inside the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process your `cmd` is supposed to be run in will be killed by the `SIGHUP` signal between the `fork()` and the `exec()`, and any `nohup` wrapper or other stuff will have no chance to run and have any effect. (You can check that with `strace`)

Instead of `nohup`, you should set `SIGHUP` to `SIG_IGN` (ignore) in the parent shell before executing your background command; if a signal handler is set to "ignore" or "default", that disposition will be inherited through `fork()` and `exec()`. Example:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
trap '' HUP    # ignore SIGHUP
xclock &
trap - HUP     # back to default
```

Or:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
(trap '' HUP; xclock &)
```

If you run this script with `xfce4-terminal -H -x script.sh`, the background command (`xclock &`) will not be killed by the `SIGHUP` sent when `script.sh` terminates.

When a session leader (a process that "owns" the controlling terminal, `script.sh` in your case) terminates, the kernel will send a `SIGHUP` to all processes from its *foreground* process group; but `set -m` will enable job control and commands started with `&` will be put in a *background* process group, and they won't signaled by `SIGHUP`.

If job control is not enabled (the default for a non-interactive script), commands started with `&` will be run in the same *foreground* process group, and the "background" mode will be faked by [redirecting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02) their input from `/dev/null` and letting them [ignore](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11) `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`.

Processes started this way from a script which once run as a foreground job but which has already exited won't be signaled with `SIGHUP` either, since their process group (inherited from their dead parent) is no longer the foreground one on the terminal.

Extra notes:

The "hold mode" seems to be different between `xterm` and `xfce4-terminal` (and probably other vte-based terminals). While the former will keep the master side of the pty open, the latter will tear it off after the program run with `-e` or `-x` has exited, causing any write to the slave side to fail with `EIO`. `xterm` will also ignore `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` messages (ie it won't close) while there are still processes from the foreground process group running.

Comment: I think you're onto something. But I'm not seeing why `xterm` would be sending a `SIGHUP` to `script.sh` in the first example from the OP. The OP doesn't say the terminal was closed

Comment: Great, this is a step forward! I have a better understanding of the behavior of the second command now. But I don't clearly see why, in the first case, we don't need anything to make `cmd` properly execute in background. Is it linked to the interactive nature of the first parent shell? Is there some implicit inheritance from it concerning SIGHUP?

Comment: in the case where `./script.sh` is not the main program on the terminal, but it's started as a foreground job from an interactive shell, its process group (also inherited by a `cmd &` started from within it) will stop being the foreground process group in the terminal as soon as it has exited. `SIGHUP` is only sent to processes from the foreground process group.

Comment: you can check all that from another window with `ps t /dev/pts/6 o pid,pgid,tpgid,sid,args` (replace `/dev/pts/6` with the actual pty). If pgid=tpgid, then this process will receive a `SIGHUP`. If pid=sid then this is the  session leader/controlling process, and pid=sid=pgid=tpgid, then it's "idle" ie it's running itself in foreground.

Comment: ok! I finally understand: all depends on what are exactly these "foreground process group" and "session leader". Thanks! I mark the question as resolved.

Comment: I  am wondering if there is a command like nohup, that will also put the process in to background after it has done the nohupping (I don't like having a special-case or race-condition).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor isn't my example doing just that? you can make it into a shell function: `bg_nohup(){ (trap '' HUP; "$@" &) }`

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with this. I can't figure it out, but here is what I have discovered. I used sleep 3 as my cmd.

These two work. I have no idea what the `ls` at the end does. The brackets and double `nohup`, well they make a sub-process (I think that is how `nohup` works). I have no idea why `nohup` on its own does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup nohup sleep 3 &
ls #no idea why I need this
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash

(
nohup sleep 3 &
ls #no idea why I need this
)
```

`/bin/true` works in place of `ls`. Seems like we need to call an external command. Still no idea why.

Comment: I think that `ls`, `/bin/true` or other external command acts as `sleep n`, in the sense that it gives sufficient time to `cmd` for being properly launched in background. Indeed, in my case, `ls` does not work every time: it depends on its execution time (`/bin/true` works more often, but not always). Likewise, I don't systematically need a double `nohup` or brackets to make it works, so I think that all of this comes down to giving some time.

Comment: what about `disown -a`

Comment: @BobJohnson how do you propose using `disown -a`? I see no advantage in by tests.