# pass function to nohup to keep command running

Tags: function, nohup

I have the following function set up which looks at a given directory and decompresses any files using qpress. It also records how long the process runs for.

```
fc_decompress () {
    startTime="$(date +%s)";
    find "$1/" -type f -iname '*.qp' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do /usr/bin/qpress -d "$f" "$(dirname "$f")" && rm "$f"; done' find-sh {} +
    endTime="$(date +%s)";
    runTime=$(( ${endTime}-${startTime} ));
    echo "Total Run Time: ${runTime}";
}
```

If I run the function as:

```
fc_decompress "${testDir}"
```

It works fine. However, on some occasions this can be a lengthy process so I figured I would run it as:

```
nohup sh -c 'fc_decompress "${testDir}"' &
```

But this no longer works, giving the error:

```
sh: fc_decompress: command not found
```

How can I pass the function into the `nohup` command so I can set it running and walk away?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16435629/10622916

Comment: If you're starting that from a shell with job control enabled, you can simply run it as `(fc_decompress "{testDir}" &)`. That won't be immune to SIGHUP, but won't be sent a SIGHUP either if the terminal is torn down. If that's not enough, you can trap the SIGHUP. Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481033/308316) for a lengthier discussion and examples.

Comment: basically, you can run your function with `bg_nohup(){ (trap '' HUP; "$@" &) }; bg_nohup func args...`

Comment: OK cheers, the `(fc_decompress "{testDir}" &)` seems to do what I need.