# nohup bash function

Tags: bash, terminal, macos, gui, nohup

In my `.bashrc`:

```bash
function keepassxc(){
    "/Applications/KeePassXC.app/Contents/MacOS/KeePassXC" "${@}"
}
export -f keepassxc
```

From Terminal:

```bash
$ nohup keepassxc
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'keepassxc': No such file or directory
```

How can I run the bash function with nohup? Actually I want to run `nohup keepassxc >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Duplicate (but without accepted answer) - [pass function to nohup to keep command running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500408/100397)

Comment: Question is about the function, but if the function is the one given, it is actually about running KeePassXC, a program, without a controlling terminal. The function is unnecessary in this case.