# Preventing xterm from killing its children

Tags: xterm, process-management, terminal-emulator

I wanted to use a window-manager key binding to open `fzf` in
`xterm` and then open the chosen file.  So I bound a key to
spawn `xterm -e fzf-open`, and put this in `fzf-open`:

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash

    # fzf-open: find a file and open it

    if file=$(find ~ -type f -name "*.pdf" |
                    fzf); then
            xdg-open "$file" &
            # disown
    fi
```

But this only works when run from the terminal.  The key binding
doesn't work, unless I remove the `&` and let the dedicated
`xterm` window hang while the opened file is open.

I take it this means that, when `xterm` dies, it takes its
children with it.  The appropriate programme is run, but killed
when xterm dies.  I tried to put `disown` after the `xdg-open
...` line, but that didn't make any difference.

How can I prevent `xterm` from taking the programme with it when
it dies?

Comment: Try this: `(trap '' HUP; xdg-open "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1 &)`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481033/308316) for an explanation.