# Unexpected behavior with shell script running a program in the background

Tags: shell-script

Running `echo "This is a test" | wc -w > num_words` results in the contents of the file `num_words` being "4". This could also be accomplished with a shell script `count_words_and_record.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
wc -w > num_words
```

Running `echo "This is a test" | ./count_words_and_record.sh` has the same outcome.

The trouble is, I am a terribly impatient person, and I want to get on to other tasks without waiting for the words to be counted. So I run `echo "This is a test" | wc -w > num_words &`, everything happens in the background, and I can run other commands immediately. Eventually, when the counting finishes, I get a message, and the contents of `num_words` is then "4". However, if I instead modify the script

```
#!/bin/bash
wc -w > num_words &
```

and run `echo "This is a test" | ./count_words_and_record.sh`, then the contents of ``num_words'' is "0" instead of "4".

What's going on here? Is there a way to modify the script to get the correct behavior?

Comment: This is answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/461386/5132 .